# How to call Tensorflow in Azure ML

Tags: tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service

I've so far seen people using tensorflow in Azure using in this [link](http://www.mikelanzetta.com/tensorflow-on-azure-using-docker.html).
Also using the advantage of ubuntu in windows tensorflow can be run on
windows pc as well.Here is the [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlayingWithTensorFlowOnWindows.aspx).
However during a conversation with Windows Azure engineer Hai Ning it came out
that "Azure ML PaaS VMs use Windows OS; TensorFlow is not supported on Windows as of now."
Hence there is no direct way of running tensorflow in Azure ML.
Is there any work around anyone figured out that allows running tensorflow in Azure ML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick update for you. As of TensorFlow r0.12 there is now a native TensorFlow package for Windows. I have it running successfully on my Windows 10 laptop. See this [blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/tensorflow-0-12-adds-support-for-windows.html) from Google for more information.